# MooTools JSON request

Tags: javascript, json, mootools, request

Trying to get a very simple request working with MooTools Request.JSON. After having no success building it from scratch, I took an example from somewhere and slowly pared it down to the bare, bare minimum, then put it back into my own page. The only things changed are the url and element ID, but to no avail.

Any help, ideas, will be greatly appreciated.

json.php

```
<?php
$result['name'] = 'yay';
header('Content-type: application/json'); 
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

demo.js (snippet inside window.addEvent('domready', function() { )

```
 $(document.body).getElement('input[id=game_name]').addEvents({
  'keydown' : function(){
   alert('hmm'); //this fires
   var jsonRequest = new Request.JSON({
    url: "json.php", 
    onComplete: function(result){ //changing to onSuccess kills everything afterwards
     alert('result.name'); //this fires
     alert(result.name); //this does not fire
     alert('result.name'); //this does not fire
    }
   }).get();
  }
 });
```

PS. in neither my page, or the pared down example pages, can i get the request to send on domready, only inside an event. why is that?

thanks again

---

As it turns out, the problem was that I had accidentally loaded a synced duplicate file into my browser that was therefore (obviously) unable to execute anything server side.

**Thank you very much for your help.**

Comment: What does accessing `json.php` directly (in your browser) show?

Comment: http://mootools.net/shell/zalun/UbYN4/ - works onload / domready just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Several suggestions/questions:

1. Are you getting any errors in your web browser's console? Which web browser are you using? The fact that the third alert doesn't fire at all suggests that `alert(result.name);` is throwing an error, in which case, all further execution will be stopped and an error will appear on your browser's console.
2. When you say "changing to onSuccess kills everything afterwards", what exactly do you mean? Does code further down (i.e. code that's not included in the above code snippet) never execute? Or does `onSuccess` just never fire?
3. Is `json.php` in the same directory as the page where this script is running? Try replacing `json.php` in `url: "json.php"` with an absolute URL (`/mydirectory/json.php` or `http://www.mywebsite.com/mydirectory/json.php`) and see whether this works.

If it's any help, the following code results in an alert reading "yay" (running on a local server; `json.php` is a file containing the PHP code in your question):

```
var jsonRequest = new Request.JSON({
    url: "json.php",
    onSuccess: function(result) {
        alert(result.name);
    }
}).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can find a great tutorial here

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/checking-username-availability-with-mootools-and-request-json/

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same problem here.
I solved it by decoding the JSON string, which is given as parameter (instead of the expected object).

```
onSuccess: function(jsonString) {
    console.log(JSON.decode(jsonString));
}
```

Here ist the documentation:
http://mootools.net/docs/core/Utilities/JSON#JSON:decode